# Scraping malformed HTML with PHP DomDocument

Tags: php, dom, xpath, domdocument

I'm using PHP DomDocument + XPath for scraping various web pages. I found that in some cases DomDocument even unable to load HTML, just returns an empty result. For example, page contains two body tags or has wrong DOCTYPE declaration. I've tried to preprocess malformed HTML with PHP Tidy and it really helps but PHP Tidy is very slow!

I don't want to use any third-party libraries like [Simple Html Dom Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net)

Please advise how to deal with malformed HTML using PHP DomDocument. Should I write a custom regexp to fix broken HTML before sending to DomDocument? Maybe I missed some settings for PHP DomDocument?

UPD

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://example.com');
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$dom = new DomDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($result);
libxml_clear_errors();
var_dump($dom);

$xpath = new DomXPath($dom);
$nodes = $xpath->query(".//*[@id='content']/ul/li/div[2]/h3/a");

var_dump($nodes); // Nothing
```

Result of var_dump($dom);

```
object(DOMDocument)#25 (34) {
  ["doctype"]=>
  string(22) "(object value omitted)"
  ["implementation"]=>
  string(22) "(object value omitted)"
  ["documentElement"]=>
  NULL
  ["actualEncoding"]=>
  string(5) "UTF-8"
  ["encoding"]=>
  string(5) "UTF-8"
  ["xmlEncoding"]=>
  string(5) "UTF-8"
  ["standalone"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["xmlStandalone"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["version"]=>
  NULL
  ["xmlVersion"]=>
  NULL
  ["strictErrorChecking"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["documentURI"]=>
  NULL
  ["config"]=>
  NULL
  ["formatOutput"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["validateOnParse"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["resolveExternals"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["preserveWhiteSpace"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["recover"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["substituteEntities"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["nodeName"]=>
  string(9) "#document"
  ["nodeValue"]=>
  NULL
  ["nodeType"]=>
  int(13)
  ["parentNode"]=>
  NULL
  ["childNodes"]=>
  string(22) "(object value omitted)"
  ["firstChild"]=>
  string(22) "(object value omitted)"
  ["lastChild"]=>
  string(22) "(object value omitted)"
  ["previousSibling"]=>
  NULL
  ["attributes"]=>
  NULL
  ["ownerDocument"]=>
  NULL
  ["namespaceURI"]=>
  NULL
  ["prefix"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["localName"]=>
  NULL
  ["baseURI"]=>
  NULL
  ["textContent"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

UPD2. Repeating `<body>` is OK for DomDocument. There were leading whitespaces in the html, solved by adding `trim()` `$dom->loadHTML(trim($result));`

Comment: Can we see the shortest possible example that causes it to fail? Two body tags is a pretty serious corruption. Is that the only case you have to process that causes it to fail?

Comment: Two body tags is terrible HTML but valid XML and DOMDocument can deal with tag soup. So yeah, an example of the HTML able to be too much for DD would be interesting to see. See also my answer for other ideas.

Comment: So far I have two cases - repeating body tags an wrong DOCTYPE like <!DOCTYPE html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#">, but more to come

Comment: Please add the bad HTML examples to your question so it makes clear how your question is different to existing ones (also please reference the existing ones and explain how those failed with your HTML).

Answer (score 2):

`DOMDocument`'s `loadHTML()` method copes fairly well with malformed HTML however it is going to generate a lot of errors. You will want to suppress these errors from bubbling up into your default error handler like this:

```
<?php
// some process of fetching the HTML page
$doc = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->loadHTML($scrappedPage);
```

It might be worthwhile using CURL to grab the file to be scrapped if you are not doing that before passing it to `DOMDocument` to be sure that you are not suffering from timeout issues while dealing with very bad HTML. This would also enable you to catch the file locally and inspect the errors that are being encountered. It would also mean that you would have a malformed HTML example to show for your next question.

Since PHP 5.4.0 and Libxml 2.6.0, you can also use the optional options parameter to give additional Libxml parameters. Some of these might be of use:

- LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD : prevents a default doctype being added when one is not found
- LIBXML_PARSEHUGE : relaxes any hardcoded limit from the parser. This affects limits like maximum depth of a document or the entity recursion, as well as limits of the size of text nodes.
- Read more: http://php.net/manual/en/libxml.constants.php

Answer (score 0):

> Should I write a custom regexp to fix broken HTML before sending to DomDocument?

Not before you haven't used Tidy and have understood why it didn't work for you and you have clear understanding how a regex could in that specific case (and in a safe and stable manner).

> Maybe I missed some settings for PHP DomDocument?

Perhaps the error handling (see [`libxml_use_internal_errors()`](http://php.net/libxml_use_internal_errors)) and the `DOMDocument::$recover` field.

But for sure you've missed the numerous existing Q&A material we have on site already about that topic. It contains much more suggestions and we have I think 10+ questions that address the error giving part of your question alone.